# create a dropdonlist and add item on onload function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I have created a dropdown list. I have added item to dropdown list on onload function.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int x = DateTime.Now.Year;
    List<string> str = new List<string>();

    for (int i = x; i >= 1975; i--)
    {

        str.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    ddlYear.DataSource = str;
    ddlYear.DataBind();

}
```

But when I click on button to submit the selected value of dropdownlist to database it always goes 2013 in my database. `ddlYear` is my dropdownlist id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the submit button page makes postback. Because of this reason dropdownlist selected value 2013. Change your code like this.

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            int x = DateTime.Now.Year;
            List<string> str = new List<string>();

            for (int i = x; i >= 1975; i--)
            {

                str.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            ddlYear.DataSource = str;
            ddlYear.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not clear what you are submitting to the database:

Try submitting `ddlyear.SelectedItem.Value` to the database.

Comment: i was try to submit selected value of dropdownlist . 
now it's working fine .
thank you very much